# When and why is /etc/init/failsafe.conf invoked on Ubuntu Server 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, boot

Could someone please tell me when during the boot process and why /etc/init/failsafe.conf is invoked?

If possible, please point me towards a resource (keyword or link) where I could read more about the bootup process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but I've been looking for the same answer myself and thought I would post at least some variety of answer for others that may be asking the same question.

failsafe.conf is a file that describes a particular job for the 'upstart' system initialization package in Ubuntu. Each .conf file in /etc/init explicitly defines an "upstart" job that starts and/or stops based on specific system events generated by *other* system startup events.

failsafe in particular starts with the loopback network interface is up and when filesystems are mounted. It won't stop until the "stop on" condition is met, which is "static-network-up" or "starting rc-sysinit". The intent, as I understand it, is to guarantee the system won't come to full boot until at least a two-minute wait has been undertaken to give every opportunity for at least one statically-defined network interface to become up and active. The two-minute wait is accomplished in stages at boot time, with messages being displayed at various intervals.

A problem can arise with failsafe imposing the two-minute wait upon systems that have no statically defined interfaces, meaning the stop-on condition defined in failsafe.conf will never be realized. This, in turn, causes failsafe to fall through to the final "boot the system without the network" configuration.

My self-education regarding failsafe.conf has arisen due to the need to overcome the assumption that I have at least one static network configuration. My machine slaves both physical NIC's to virtual bridges, meaning the static-network-up condition will never be achieved. As a result, I am faced with a decidedly unwanted delay at bootup. To date, my only choice has been to eliminate the various sleep timers within failsafe.conf. I've not yet found a stop condition matching my system that failsafe will abide and terminate..alas.

Comment: I did find a solution to the timeout. I had to remove all auto xxxxx linesnin /etc/networks/interfaces and write manual upstart scripts for each net device, bringing up each such interface manually.